# In a test of 6 questions each scored out of 10 marks, in how many ways can you score a decreasing (non-increasing) set of marks?

Tags: combinatorics

I have actually solved this problem and there are 8008 ways. But this is equal to 16C10 and I have no idea why?! So that is the problem I would like help with. It is (6+10)C10 and I am a bit haunted that there must be a simple argument as to why? Perhaps involving a 'stars and bars' approach.

I used partitions to solve the problem and more specifically partitions into at most 6 parts and partitions in which the greatest part is 10. This involved considering Ferrers diagrams and their conjugates. I asked in how many ways can every possible total from 0 to 60 can be scored. I then summed these answers to get 8008. The number of ways of scoring for each individual total sometimes involved summing a bounded partition with a sum of bounded partitions and a double sum of bounded partitions.

But for all this difficult work, there is the simple answer of 16C10. I then wrote a 'brute-force calculation' programme to see if the pattern generalises and it does seem to. For 5,6,7,8 and 9 questions with 10 marks per question the answers are 15C10, 16C10, 17C10, 18C10 and 19C10. Can anyone please help explain how to get the simple answer of 16C10? Thank you so much in advance, this is my first post on Maths Stack Exchange, I am a maths teacher.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Given any collection of scores, there is a unique way to sort them in non-decreasing order.  Thus you are just asking for the number of $10-$tuples of non-negative integers that sums to $6$, the standard Stars and Bars problem.  Here, the $10-$tuple $(a_1, \cdots, a_{10})$ means that you got exactly $a_i$ scores of $i$ (doesn't matter which questions got those scores).

Comment: This is very elegant! I think that you may mean an 11-tuple, as 0 -10 is 11 possible marks for a question. So a test score of 865532 maps to the 11-tuple (0,0,1,1,0,2,1,0,1,0,0). And each 11 tuple only maps to one non-decreasing score. So there is a bijection and we can use 10 bars and 6 stars giving (10+6)C10 ways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for integers $q_1,\ldots,q_6$ we have $10 \ge q_1 \ge q_2 \ge q_3 \ge q_4 \ge q_5 \ge q_6 \ge 0$ if and only if the sequence $$(10 - q_1,q_1 - q_2,q_2 - q_3.q_3 - q_4,q_4-q_5,q_5-q_6,q_6)$$ consists of non-negative integers which add up to $10$. How many sequences of $7$ nonnegative integers add up to $10$? Stars and bars says its $\binom{16}{10}$. Do you see how to generalize this to $n$ questions? What if each question is scored out of $k$ marks?

Comment: So you have come up with a 7-tuple whose elements represent in order, the decrease in mark from 10 to the mark for the first question followed by the decrease in mark from question to next question, followed by the mark for the last question, which must add up to 10. This is intuitively because we have 10 marks we can drop (as our upper limit) and we keep taking (possibly zero) marks off until we finally have an amount left and these subtractions and the remainder must add up to the original 10 marks. This 7-tuple is then seen to be any sequence of non-negative numbers adding to 10.

Comment: So, there is a bijection between ways of adding non-negative integers to a total of 10 and numbers of ways to drop marks. So we count the set in the bijection using stars and bars. To generalise we have number of questions n and number of marks per question m and then we have (n+m)Cm ways. Very clear explanation.